# Freeing space by Formating the size of citations on slides in Beamer using Biblatex

Tags: beamer, biblatex, fontsize

I want to change the size of my citations on the slides. My relevant preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{biblio1.bib}
%---------------Document-----------------------%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
%\nocite{*}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

Up until now I do it likes this:

```
{\tiny\parencite{Harris.12}}
```

**Question:** Is there an option to format this for all citations in the beamer-presentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\citesetup` to provide code to be executed at the beginning of each citation command; a little example (in the example I changed the style and the `.bib` file used, but this is not important):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand\citesetup{\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
As we can see in~\parencite{angenendt}, this experiment was succesful. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]